# Group isomorphism between the two groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $(G, \cdot)$ be a group with identity element $e$ and choose an element $a \in G$. Then define a operation $'*'$ on $G$ by $x * y = xay$. Clearly $(G, *)$ is closed and associative. Suppose $x * e' = x$, it implies that  $e'  = a^{-1}$, which is the  identity element of $G$ associated  with the binary operation $*$. For any $x \in G$, there is $y \in G$ such that $x*y =  y*x =e'$, where $y = a^{-1}x^{-1}a^{-1}.$ Thus $(G, *)$ is a group.

> > Is $(G, \cdot)$ is isomorphic to $(G, *)$

I would be thankful if someone help me to solve it.

Comment: Try the map $G \to (G,*)$ defined by $x \mapsto xa^{-1}$.

Comment: This is working, thanks for the hint. It helped me alot.

Answer (score 2):

If we take $f:(G,\cdot) \rightarrow (G,*)$ such that $f(x)=a^{-1}x$ we have that:
$$f(x \cdot y)=a^{-1}xy=a^{-1}xaa^{-1}y=f(x)*f(y)$$
so it is an homomorphism between groups,
now take $ x \in (G,\cdot) \rightarrow f(x)=a^{-1}x=z \in (G,*)$ since $a^{-1}x=z \in G$ and also $z \in (G,*) \rightarrow  f^{-1}(z)=az=x \in (G,\cdot)$ since $az=x \in G$, so the map is bijective and it is an isomorphism .